# Stokes' theorem for multiply connected regions (with n holes)

Tags: vectors, vector-analysis, stokes-theorem

What will be the reduced form of the Stokes' theorem for multiply connected regions (with n holes)?

If S is a surface in space with n holes with boundaries of the holes as $C_1, C_2, \dots, C_n$ then

$$\int\int_S \nabla \times F\cdot n\, dS=\sum_{i=1}^n \int_{C_i} F.dr$$

The outer circle $C$ is positively oriented, and the inner circles $C_i$ negatively

Is this true?

1. Please correct if not true.
2. Also give a good reference where one can study Stokes' theorem for such surfaces.

[image]

Comment: You have to be careful with what you mean by holes. If the surface is (topologically) a sphere with $n$ (topological) disks removed and you orient the boundary curves correctly, then your formula is correct.

Comment: @Arkady  If the surface is (topologically) a sphere with n (topological) disks removed $\int\int_S \nabla \times F\cdot n\, dS=\int_{C} F.dr+\sum_{i=1}^n \int_{C_i} F.dr$ C=outer boundary of S, C_i are boundary of each hole...which one is right? Any reference of this topic?

Answer (score 1):

An intuitive explanation of why it works.

You can decompose S into n+1 surfaces with no hole: the boundary between surface i and surface i+1 touches hole i twice (I hope this is understandable without a drawing).

Then the left hand-side double integral is the sum of n+1 same integrals over each of the n+1 sufaces; and the right hand-side is the sum of n+1 same integrals over the n+1 boundaries, because at each frontier between two surfaces the two integrals cancel each other.

So the usual Stokes formula can be applied separately to each of the n+1 surfaces, and the sum of these n+1 equations gives the result.